# Equivalent of chrome://inspect/#workers on Opera

Tags: debugging, opera, web-worker, opera-blink

`chrome://inspect/#workers` is the debugging page for web workers on Chrome.

What is the equivalent of this page on Opera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`opera://inspect/#workers` is the one. It's available on Opera 30+ Stable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [developer version of Opera](http://www.opera.com/developer) (this won't work when you're on the main stream), and browse to:

```
browser://inspect/#workers
```

(Sorry, SO won't let me make that into a proper link.)

Comment: Incidentally, `vivaldi://inspect/#workers` will work on Vivaldi as well (I'm switching to Vivaldi more and more), since all three browsers have Blink under the hood. Not sure why ChrOpera uses `browser` instead of `opera`, but I just checked, and you can prefix either `opera` or `chrome` and it'll recognise it, but just convert it to `browser`.